# customizing header and footer in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to customize the header and footer in magento according to my needs but when I tried modifying header it reflected the changes from the default magento header to my customized header but when I am trying to change my footer the changes in header are not shown only footer changes are being reflected 
I have added the blocks in local.xml file and the customization for header and footer in header.phtml and footer.phtml file respectively local.xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
       <checkout_cart_index>
          <reference name="header">
             <block type="page/header" name="header">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                   <template>checkout/cart/footer/header.phtml</template>
                </action>
             </block>
          </reference>
       </checkout_cart_index>
       <checkout_cart_index>
          <reference name="footer_html">
             <block type="page/footer" name="footer">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                   <template>checkout/cart/footer/footer.phtml</template>
                </action>
             </block>
          </reference>
       </checkout_cart_index>
    </layout>
```

I want to both header and footer changes getting reflected simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake in the template section instead of passing the path for header.phtml I have bymistakely passed the path for footer.phtml